# Java datatypes to Typescript types

Tags: java, angular, typescript

I am trying to create an Interface in Angular 8. I would like to have type defined for every Json property and the back-end uses Spring/Java

```
Java Code and types:
private TestDto(
    @JsonProperty("id") **String** id,
    @JsonProperty("version") **long** version,
    @JsonProperty("modifyDate") **Instant** modifyDate,
    @JsonProperty("duration") **Duration** duration,
    @JsonProperty("testValue") **Float** testValue
)

What should be in the Angular Interface?
export interface Example {
    id: string;
    version:
    modifyDate:
    duration:
    testValue:
}

Thank you in advance.
```

Comment: Define a json schema and auto-generate both from the schema. [to Typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-schema-to-typescript) and [to Java](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Comment: or simpy use a [generator](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Comment: you can use swagger to convert your java dtos to typescript interfaces